# hosting an application in glassfish

Tags: dns, hosting, glassfish-3, vps

I have installed glassfish 3.1 application server. created a domain and all. deployed war file and its working fine in local machine. now my problem is:

- I have purchased a domain e.g: abc.com
- How to add this domain in glassfish server
- I have an VPS hosting space too where i have installed the glassfish server.
- where can i give name server to this domain in glass fish?
- How can i host an website/web application in glassfish?
- Please any body guide me with this.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to make sure that DNS resolution is working correctly and that the domain name points to your server's IP address.

Then you can configure Glassfish 3.x to listen to this domain name:

- open administration console
- go to configurations --> network-configuration --> network listeners --> http-listener 1/2
- switch to the "HTTP" tab and enter your domain and port in the field "server name", e.g. `www.yourdomain.com:8080`
- save the configuration and test it.

Comment: how to configure DNS and IP address in glassfish? I am stuck in this

Comment: First check if it isn't yet correctly configured. If you ping your domain, will it return your IP address?

Comment: www.yourdomain.com:8080 But when add www.yourdomain.com will not work how to make it